# How to mark git commit as merged in git history without actually merging them?

Tags: git, git-merge

i have 100 commits in develop branch which are not in featureX branch. I want to ensure the 3 commits in develop do not get merged into featureX when i run "git merge".

Is there a way to selectively mark those 3 commits as being merged into featureX branch without actually merging them?

I asked chatgpt and looked for questions/answers here. But didn't found anything relevant to my case.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox and Donat.. The commits in develop are relating to a folders that has been removed in featureX branch. So, rather than resolving them, we are preferring to do this way.

Comment: When you merge the branches, you should receive a merge conflict ("modify/delete") on the files in question. Then resolve them as needed, which would be to `git rm` the files. This is just bog standard procedure. No special considerations are needed for the case.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ours`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-ours-1) merge [strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt--sltstrategygt). It does merge (to store the very fact of merge) but doesn't change files, it always takes the current tree:

```
git merge -s ours -m "Null-merge featureX into develop" featureX
```

PS. Do not confuse `-s ours` with [`-X ours`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-ours), these are two completely different options.